# Connecting to LibreOffice with named pipes

Tags: python, openoffice.org, named-pipes, libreoffice, uno

I can connect with sockets just fine, but I heard that using pipes is faster when everything is local, so I wanted to try it out, but I can't get a connection.

I start Libre with

```
 > soffice --headless --invisible --norestore --nodefault --nolockcheck --nofirstwizard --accept='pipe,name=ooo_pipe;urp;'
```

And the bare minimum python script that should work but doesn't is

```
import uno
from com.sun.star.connection import NoConnectException

pipe = 'ooo_pipe'
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext)
context = resolver.resolve("uno:pipe,name=%s;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" % pipe)
```

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work? What do you expect this script to do? What do you see instead?

Answer (score 7):

I've used socket mode so far. Just tested pipe on my machine by the cmd:

```
/usr/lib/openoffice/program/soffice.bin -accept='pipe,name=foo;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' -nologo -headless -nofirststartwizard -invisible

$ lsof -c soffice|egrep "pipe|foo"
soffice.b 6698 user    3r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 15766935 pipe
soffice.b 6698 user    4w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 15766935 pipe
soffice.b 6698 user   15u  unix 0xffff88009773ed00      0t0 15767001 /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_foo
```

lsof shows that there is a named socket foo and its OK to get the connection in Python. At the start of the experiment, there were occasions that no foo is generated and hence com.sun.star.connection.NoConnectException was raised. But I can't repeat this error after that.

We've used socket-mode headless soffice in production for several years and its very stable and fast enough. Seems pipe mode here still relies on unix socket, so I suggest using socket mode.